# Are wallet credentials really safe?

Tags: wallet, open-source, copay

I’m using Copay as my Bitcoin wallet. I see it is opensource with the code available in github. What guarantees that they uploaded binary based on that source code? Does it go through Apple approval? Storing more money in bitcoin, I want to be sure my password / credentials are safe and that the developers are not sending out in a hidden way, via backdoor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any guarantee. You are relying completely on the developers to submit the binary application file based on that source. You are also relying on Apple not to manipulate the application binary once it gets to them.

It's no different with Bitcoin Core or any other wallet or software. In all cases you're putting your trust in whoever does the build and the source and tools they use.

One option is to look at the history of the software. If it's relatively mature and has had no faults, either malicious or competency related, then it may be safe to put a degree of trust in it.

Comment: Is web based bitcoin transaction more save? There I can see HTML code. Or is it any server side programming need to do a transaction?

Comment: Web based is even riskier, look at Mt Gox and the many other similar cases. Safest is a hardware wallet such as Ledger or Trezor.

Answer (score 1):

Would not a paper wallet be considered the safest ?
Only you know under which stone you tucked away the note about
private key and backup phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it safe because is not like bank account and no óne can hack it wallet account unless the person share his deatials to someone